# Extended Euclidean Algorithm to find multiplicative inverse of two polynomials

Tags: polynomials, coding-theory, euclidean-algorithm

I asked [Using Extended Euclidean Algorithm to find multiplicative inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505902/using-extended-euclidean-algorithm-to-find-multiplicative-inverse/1506007#1506007) earlier, and understand how to use EEA for two integers. Now I'd like to do it with polynomials, but I'm getting some very large fractions following the same procedure as I did w/ the integers. The problem I'm working on is:
$(x^5 + x^2 + 1)^{-1} \cdot mod  (x^{10} + x^3 + 1)$

\begin{align}
x^{10} + x^3 + 1&=(x^5-x^2-1)\cdot(x^5+x^2+1)+(x^4+x^3+2x^2+2)\\
(x^5+x^2+1)&=(x-1)\cdot(x^4+x^3+2x^2+2)+(-x^3+3x^2-2x+3)\\
(x^4+x^3+2x^2+2)&=(-x-4)\cdot(-x^3+3x^2-2x+3)+(12x^2-5x+14)\\
(-x^3+3x^2-2x+3)&=(\frac{31}{144}-\frac{x}{12})\cdot(12x^2-5x+14)+(\frac{35x}{144}-\frac{1}{72})\\
12x^2-5x+14&=(\frac{1728x}{35}-\frac{21744}{1225})\cdot(\frac{35x}{144}-\frac{1}{72})+\frac{16848}{1225}
\end{align}
Continuing from there, I start to get some big fractions, which doesn't seem correct. I know the GCD is 1, but it doesn't look like I'm going to get that following the above procedure. What is the issue here?

Comment: you just go ahead two steps at most and then go backwards. It works!

Comment: I continued two more steps and edited my post to reflect that. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GCD of two polynomials is only unique up to multiplication by an (invertible) element of the base field. You can freely renormalise to work with smaller coefficients.

$$\begin{align}
x^{10} + x^3 + 1&=(x^5-x^2-1)\cdot(x^5+x^2+1)+(x^4+x^3+2x^2+2)\\
(x^5+x^2+1)&=(x-1)\cdot(x^4+x^3+2x^2+2)+(-x^3+3x^2-2x+3)\\
(x^4+x^3+2x^2+2)&=(-x-4)\cdot(-x^3+3x^2-2x+3)+(12x^2-5x+14)\\
(-x^3+3x^2-2x+3)&=\frac{1}{144}\left((31-12x)\cdot(12x^2-5x+14)+(35x-2) \right)\\
12x^2-5x+14&=\frac{1}{1225}\left((420x - 151)(35x - 2) + 16848 \right)
\end{align}$$

The numbers aren't much smaller in this case, but the point is that the GCD is a constant, so the two polynomials are coprime.

Comment: Oh so the GCD doesn't have to be 1 when it's polynomials? Just a constant?

Comment: If a polynomial has no remainder when divided by 1, it has no remainder when divided by 2, and vice versa.

Comment: So, when working my way back up, can I ignore the 1/1225 and 1/144? Otherwise, where would I place the fractions? For instance, my first line would be 16848 = ...  
Should I make it instead $(1/1225)\cdot16848=(1/1225)\cdot...$